# What is the correct way to set State according to fetch data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I did search about this but I could not find explanation which way should be valid and followed.

If we want to add new data our state , for sure we are using *immutable* way like map the entire data to create new array or filter to delete and so on. However I cannot figure out which way is appropriate when data is fetched from server and why? Do I really need to iterate entire array or create deep copy of object?

### Way 1

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(myJson => {
        const newData = [];
        myJson.forEach(item => newData.push(item));
        setData(newData);
      });
  }, []);
```

### Way 2

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(myJson => {      
        setData(myJson);
      });
  }, []);
```

Comment: Can't see the reason why I wouldn't do the 'Way2'

Comment: way1 unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

In class components, we have state object which we are updating and getting values from. In that case, *immutable* state could be a concern.

In functional components, you can get over *immutable* state because we are referring to a single entity/value at a time. So, your second code sample would be a good way to go.

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(myJson => {      
        setData(myJson);
      });
  }, []);
```

Comment: As far as I understand, we should not concern about immutability if we are fetching even if class component. For sure I am not talking about updating current state.

Comment: Yes, That might be the case.

Answer (score 1):

Both way are setting state using immutable way, to me if you need to process the data for example filter, format, or delete in the frontend, you will need to use way 1. If the data do not need to be processed, I will recommend way 2. Furthermore I will recommend prepare the data as you needed in the database or backend, then send it to frontend.